# regex produces not what I need

Tags: python, regex

Re.sub replaces text with parentheses
The code:

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'sizeOfWindow\b[^.]','x234234','sizeOfWindow.(sizeOfWindow)'))
```

I want `sizeOfWindow. (X234234)` , but it prints `sizeOfWindow. (X234234`
What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: Try `print(re.sub(r'(?<=\()sizeOfWindow(?=\))','x234234','sizeOfWindow.(sizeOfWindow)'))`

Comment: use something like this `"sizeOfWindow\.\s\(.*\)$"`

Comment: `re.sub(r'(sizeOfWindow\.)\([^)]*', r'\1 (X234234','sizeOfWindow.(sizeOfWindow)')` - [demo](https://ideone.com/hVfCJi). However, this is a guess since it is not clear what exactly you want to match.

Comment: sorry, my question was not entirely correct

all this does not work in my case, I need re.sub to replace a certain word that does not end with a dot, but in this situation, if there is some special character after the word, it is replaced with

Comment: *"my question was not entirely correct"*: you can edit your question...

Comment: Like this then? `sizeOfWindow\b(?!\.)` https://regex101.com/r/3ftGiK/1

Comment: @discared Did any of the answers work out?

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment

> I need re.sub to replace a certain word that does not end with a dot

This part `[^.]` is a negated character class that matches a single char other than a dot, that is why it matches the parenthesis and is it gone after the replacement.

You can use a negative lookahead instead asserting not a dot directly to the right.

```
import re
 
print(re.sub(r'sizeOfWindow\b(?!\.)','x234234','sizeOfWindow.(sizeOfWindow)'))
```

Output

```
sizeOfWindow.(x234234)
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JsEBIG)

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on your comments and based on fourth birds regex in the comments, but using a negative lookahead instead:

```
print(re.sub(r'sizeOfWindow(?![.])','x234234','sizeOfWindow.(sizeOfWindow)'))
```

This should match the word, if it is not immediately followed by `.`

Comment: it would help if it was not important for me whether to put a parenthesis at the end or not, I need the re.sub that not to replace the parentheses at the end